# Swiftmailer in Symfony not returning error even with wrong server

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

I just started to use Swiftmailer with Symfony 3 and it is sending e-mail fine, but when I insert a configuration error on purpose, like changing the name of the server for a faulty one, I don't get any errors from the "send" method. The code follows:

```
$message = new \Swift_Message('Teste SICOS');

$message->setFrom(['nao-responda@sicos.xxx.gov.br' => 'SICOS'])
    ->setTo('joaoxxx@gmail.com')
    ->setBody("teste");
    $res = $this->get("mailer")->send($message, $failures);
    if (!$res){
        $msg = "houve um erro no envio do e-mail. ".$failures;
    } else {
        $msg = "E-mail enviado.";
    }
    dump($failures);
```

In the config.yml I use:

```
swiftmailer:
    host:      xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxx
    port:      25
    spool:     { type: memory }
```

Both when I use the correct server configuration and the wrong one, the result of the `send` method `$res` is `1`, which, I think, means, the e-mail has been sent. But the profiler does show the following error:

`Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Connection could not be established with host xxxx [php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Este host n�o � conhecido. #0]`

Why doesn't the send method return an error and how can I get it to return one, so I can show a message to the users saying something went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that problem was with the configuration

`spool:     { type: memory }`

With this on, the e-mail is not sent right away, but it's saved for sending later.